# iOS 7 32bit and 64bit project Build Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, iphone-5

I have already convert 32bit ios7 project in 64bit mode with Xcode5.  Now I want to test it in latest iPhone device ?

**Are there any changes or requirement needed to test the Project?**

What are the other option to test this project without iPhone device?

Comment: Use xcode simulator ios7 in xcode5

Answer (score 0):

Change your Destination to a 64bit simulator and run. I'm a little unclear why your sentence "Now I want to test it in latest iPhone device" has a question mark.

[image: Destination drop down]